# Improve the speed of message/comment notifications?

Tags: support, notifications, comment-replies

Hard to know for sure, but I've been noticing that I'm not getting notifications for new messages, comments in a timely manner (15+ hours?)

Comment: Do you have an example (e.g. a specific comment you didn't get a notification for)?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I don't remember a specific one.  But over the past two days, I keep getting the notification envelope, but I click it and nothing new shows up for any of the selectable time periods.  Also, I'm being told I have changes to my favorites, but again, it doesn't show me what the changes are.